# My index suddenly having "Trying to get property of non-object" after doing edit and create blade

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined

Thank you guys for helping me last time. the problem I am having right now is regarding with my view blade. This index.blade is completely working before I create the, edit and create blade. After I completed the the other two blade, I noticed the index.blade are now having **Trying to get property of non-object**

what I'm trying to do is to display category in products table.

**Product Table**
id , name, categories_id

**Categories Table**
id, name

**Products Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Products extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_code',
        'name',
        'categories_id',
        'wh1_limit_warning',
        'wh2_limit_warning',
        'price',
        'selling_price',
        'user_id'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function category() {
        // return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'categories_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Categories Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Categories extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function Products()
    {
        // return $this->hasMany(Products::class);
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'categories_id');    
    }
}
```

**Index Blade**

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="result-set">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover text-center" id="data-table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Code</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Name</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Category</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-center"><small>Warehouse 1<br/>Limit Warning</small></th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-center"><small>Warehouse 2<br/>Limit Warning<small></th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Price</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Selling Price</th>
                                @can('update_product', 'delete_product')
                                <th class="text-center col-md-1 text-center">Actions</th>
                                @endcan
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($products as $product)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $product->product_code }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                                    <td><b>{{ $product->category->name }}</b></td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->wh1_limit_warning }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->wh2_limit_warning }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->selling_price }}</td>
                                    @can('update_product')
                                    <td>
                                        <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update product" onclick="window.location='{{ route('products.edit', $product) }}'" name="edit" class="action-button edit">
                                        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <form action="{{ route('products.delete', $product )}}" method="post">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                            <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete product" type="submit" class="action-button delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    @endcan
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Products Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Products;
use App\Categories;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $products = Products::with('category')->get();
        return view('products.index')->with('products',$products);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $products = Products::with('category')->get();
        $categories = Categories::get()->pluck('name','id');
        return view('products.create',compact('categories'))->with('products', $products);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $products = Products::create($request->only(
            'product_code',
            'name',
            'categories_id',
            'wh1_limit_warning',
            'wh2_limit_warning',
            'price',
            'selling_price',
            'user_id'
        ));

        $this->validate($request, [
            'product_code' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'categories_id' => 'required|integer',
            'wh1_limit_warning' => 'required|integer',
            'wh2_limit_warning' => 'required|integer',
            'price' => 'required|integer',
            'selling_price' => 'required|integer',
            'user_id' => 'required|integer', 
        ]);

        flash('New product added!');
        return redirect(route('products.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Products  $products
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Products $products)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Products  $products
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Products $product)
    {
        $products = Products::all();
        $categories = Categories::all('name','id');
        return view('products.edit',compact('product','categories'));

        //return view('products.edit',compact('product','categories'))->with('products', $products);
        // return view('products.edit', compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Products  $products
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Products $product)
    {
        $product->update($request->only(
            'product_code',
            'name',
            'categories_id',
            'wh1_limit_warning',
            'wh2_limit_warning',
            'price',
            'selling_price',
            'user_id'
        ));
        return redirect()->route('products.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Products  $products
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Products $product)
    {
        $product->delete();
        return redirect(route('products.index'));
    }
}
```

I can't see where did I go wrong because I did not change anything in     public function index() of my controller. Again, EDIT and Create is workingI was able to display the categories in dropdown with no any issue only this index.blade.

[Please see this screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJMUp.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: where does the error actually appears? on page load? on create?

Comment: on page load(index.blade.php)

Comment: I just update my post. I add the link of the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your query returns an array instead of an object. Try dumping your return to make sure.

If it is an array, you can try using `[]` instead of `->` in your **index.blade.php**:

```
<td><b>{{ $product->category['name'] }}</b></td>
```

Comment: Apology @community I have to give the check to kamal because he answer first.

Comment: @LitoLozada mine is 21 mins ago  his is 10 mins ago as of now :D

Comment: Oh yes! hahaha just transfer the check hahaha. But my fellow newbees these both works!

Answer (score 1):

Seems there will be some product which don't have any category. So that product wont be linked with any category and it won't have any category object that's why it is giving this error.

You can add a check before displaying the category name that product contains category or not.

```
<td><b>{{ $product->category ? $product->category->name : "" }}</b></td>
```

Comment: @LitoLozada Happy to help you :)

Comment: @LitoLozada does `$product->category->name` shows the product name? or it's always blank?

Comment: This should display category name why product name?

Comment: @community because I am using productController i guess sorry not even sure. I am completely newbee here. :D :D